# RxJS - Piped observable re-running too often

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Upon clicking a button, I want to switch to my file$ observable, check that it is populated, and use it to upload the file inside `uploadRates(file, date)`.

```
const click$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.uploadButton.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.file$),
    filter(file => !!file && !!this.dateForRates),
    tap(_ => this.isLoading$.next(true)),
    exhaustMap(file => this.uploadRates(file, this.dateForRates))
).subscribe({
    next: x => {
        this.handleUploadRatesResult(x);
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
    complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
    error: err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    }
});
```

It works, but I just don't want any of that pipe to re-run when i do something like `this.file$.next(undefined);` elsewhere in code, and it does. I only want it to run when I click the button. How do I cause the pipe in `ngOnInit` to re-run only when clicking the button, but still extract the file from my `file$` variable to check it is populated and upload it upon clicking the button?

Comment: Is the `file$` observable of type RxJS `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: @MichaelD yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `file$` does not complete after it has emitted a value. This means that the inner subscription will be kept active.

What you could to is to add a `take(1)` to make sure it won't be subscribed to it anymore after the first emitted value:

```js
switchMapTo(this.file$.pipe(take(1))),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `withLatestFrom` operator. It will subscribe to the given observable and store the latest value, but not emit if the observable itself emits:

```
const click$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.uploadButton.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.file$),
    map(([_, file]) => file),
    filter(file => !!file && !!this.dateForRates),
    tap(_ => this.isLoading$.next(true)),
    exhaustMap(file => this.uploadRates(file, this.dateForRates))
).subscribe({
    next: x => {
        this.handleUploadRatesResult(x);
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
    complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    },
    error: err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually condone the use of RxJS `BehaviorSubject`s [`value`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L19) getter. It can be used to synchronously get the current value held by the observable. But in this case it could be exploited to avoid subscribing to the observable. Try the following

```js
const click$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.uploadButton.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    map(() => this.file$.value),       // <-- use the `value` getter here
    filter(file => !!file && !!this.dateForRates),
    tap(_ => this.isLoading$.next(true)),
    exhaustMap(file => this.uploadRates(file, this.dateForRates))
).subscribe({
  ...
```